# How can I make the internal block's border stick outside of the parent block

Tags: html, css

I want to make an `<h4>` block stick outside of the `<div>` block like the word
RESULT is sticking out in the photo. I've tried increasing the padding and border but it doesn't seem to help

[image: 1]

```css
h4{
  text-align:left;
  width:90px;
  margin-top:10px;
  }
```

Comment: please include your image into your question, avoid external links.

Comment: Why not `left: -.5em` or some similar value?

Answer (score 0):

Can you maybe make the h4 position absolute and the parent class position relative. That way when you make the h4, top 0 left 0 it will be on the edge of the parent element?